# Being sensitive to uppercase and lowercase in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a capcha code for example i have in database table it as:`Nag14I` .if i put it as:`nag14i` in following mysql query i have a output:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM captcha WHERE word = 'nag14i' AND captcha_time > '$expiration'";
print_r($query); //[num_rows] => 1
```

I have in out put as:

```
word = Nag14I => [num_rows] => 1 
word = nag14I => [num_rows] => 0 
word = Nag14i => [num_rows] => 0 
word = nag14i => [num_rows] => 0
```

How can match all letters if is uppercase or lowercase by mysql query?

Comment: Cool. Now ask a question.

Comment: WHERE word = 'nag14i' aren't you missing commas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL isn't case-sensitive by default, in order to make a query case-sensitive try the BINARY operator:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM captcha WHERE BINARY word = nag14i AND captcha_time > '$expiration'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using case-sensitive matching, you should us a case-sensitive or binary collation for the field.  This will allow you to get the results you expect.